# Screen Flow - Address Lightning Component is missing the CountryCode

Tags: screen-flow, address

I am using the Address Lightning component in a screen flow.
I have State and Country picklist enabled, so when the user selects a country, the state is enabled or not.

[image]

The problem is that the 'Country' value, and 'State' values, are saved as the value/name/label, and not the API 2 char code.

I don't see any additional settings on the Address component.

[image]

And when I create the lead, the Country code is empty, while the country has the value from the Picklist.

I am trying multiple scenarios:

But getting same issue: The country code in the object only gets the Name from the Address, and not the Value
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? I was able to use the address component and take the selected Country/state and have the Lead created correctly (CountryCode & StateCode auto-populate after insert based on value set in Country & State). Are you trying to use the values later on in your Flow - have you re-queried the created Lead record after you've created it?

Comment: Thank you, I am using the values from the address component to query other metadata, which is stored as iso_char values. This is done in a before flow on the lead. I don't want to create the lead, and than reevaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Address component only provides you with values as you noted and as is [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_address.htm&type=5).

If you were to insert the record, then `CountryCode` & `StateCode` would be populated based on the value you passed to the record.

Since you indicated you can't do that (insert & then re-query), you'll have to do handle the mapping yourself based on the value you're given. You have a couple options

1. Use Invocable [apex](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338321&type=1) to get the code based on the value

```java
String countryCode;
String stateCode;

//get CountryCode
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = User.Countrycode.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
System.debug('Picklist::'+ple);
for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
    if(f.getLabel() == yourCountryValue){
        //store value of code
        countryCode = f.getValue();
    }
}

//get StateCode
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = User.statecode.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
System.debug('Picklist::'+ple);
for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
    if(f.getLabel() == yourStateValue){
        stateCode = f.getValue();
    }
}

//return values back to Flow to use in query
```

2. Load in a Custom Setting or Custom Metadata Type a mapping of Country/State Values you can query in the Flow directly to get the corresponding code based on value.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a channel where we can report or upvote the need to fix this Screenflow issue w/ Salesforce?

Another work-around option if you need to stay in Flows:

- Create a temporary contact record with the Mailing Country set.
- Save then retrieve the record and assign the Mailing Country Code to a variable
- Rollback database changes
- Assign the variable's value to the destination Country Code field

Answer (score 0):

I am the Product Manager for our screen flow components. Proper support for State and Country Picklists is coming soon, check out this idea for more updates: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgLIUAZ/flow-screen-components-include-validation-options-and-required-attributes

We're also adding a number of other fun features like Disabled, Required, and Google Address Lookup!